# GSON + InAppBilling + ProGuard --> App doesn't working

Tags: android, gson, proguard, in-app-billing

I've activated proguard in my application to obfuscate my code. The problem is my activity where InAppBilling happens, does not working anymore. First I get an successful request from my own server and then nothing happens. It seems for me that GSON is crashing. I already use this code on my proguard config file but it doesn't solve the problem:

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature
# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*
# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

I hope someone has a solution to this problem.

Best regards
Andy

Comment: have you tried keeping all gson library not obsuscated? Its source code is public, so you can leave it out of proguard..
Or you can see [this example](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg)

Comment: The proguard config seems fine and it's in line with the recommended settings (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg). What kind of crash are you getting? Can you provide a stacktrace and logcat output

Comment: How can I exclude an library? Like this: -keep class gson-2.2.2.** { *; }
I already found that example you posted but it doesn't work for me. The problem is, I can't find any error message. Thx for your help.

Comment: I've made Log Outputs:
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
   Log.d(TAG, "GSON1");
   try {
    Packages packages = gson.fromJson(content, Packages.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "GSON2");
    items = packages.getPackages();
    final List<String> itemList = new ArrayList();
    Bundle queryItems = new Bundle();
    Log.d(TAG, "Size GSON: " + items.size());
The last log (Size GSON) doesn't show up. No crash, no error, it only stops

Comment: I have the solution. You also have to exclude the objects/classes where your content from JSON is mapped to! Thanks for your help, it forces me to investigate more into that problem.